# Rails3 CookieOverflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubycas, session-store

I am getting this error:

```
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow
```

In config/application.rb I have:

```
config.session_store :active_record_store
```

There is no data being stored in the sessions table.

I am using RubyCAS-client with this code:
https://github.com/zuk/rubycas-client-rails

Am I doing something wrong to have the code stored in the database or is this code not setup to use active record store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was doing it in config/application.rb.  When I changed it in config/initializers/session_store.rb it worked.

I don't know if this is completely right because I assume config/application.rb is the place it should be?